# automake: how set path to linker script?

Tags: gcc, ld, autoconf, automake

I've just set up a cross-helloworld automake project (for stm32f4-discovery). There I have a custom *discovery.ld* scrpt. I put a line in my *Makefile.am*`AM_LDFLAGS = -T discovery.ld`. The problem starts when I run *confgure* from a different folder (e.g. */path/to/source/build*) to the one in which the script is situated (*/path/to/source*). Effectively, being in */path/to/source/build* directory, *make* runs `gcc -T discovery.ld ...` and fails to find the script because it's in */path/to/source* directory and it's not included in the search path list.

`-L/path/to/source` or `-L..` would solve the problem but I don't want to hardcode things.

Maybe there a autoconf/automake variable exists which points to the folder where *configure* script (and also my *discovery.ld*) are situated so that I could use it in my *Makefile.am*?

I'd be glad to any advice.

Comment: `AM_LDFLAGS = -T $(top_srcdir)/path/to/discovery.ld`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to William Pursell:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -T $(top_srcdir)/path/to/discovery.ld
```